How to specify --extra-cflags and --extra-ldflags when cross compiling?
I am using the cross compiler aarch64-none-linux-gnu.
Now I am trying to compile ffmpeg for aarch64 for a board with arm cpu.
My question is when I run script like:
export SYSROOT=/mnt/d/Libs/cross-compilers/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc

./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --cross-prefix=${CROSS_PREFIX} \
    --sysroot=${SYSROOT} \
    --arch=aarch64 \
    --target-os=linux \
    --host-os=linux \
    --enable-libvpx \
    --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include/vpx" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib"

Does the compiler will search headers in /usr/local/include/vpx or ${SYSROOT}/usr/local/include/vpx (the absolute path)?
In other words, will the compiler add ${SYSROOT} prefix to the -I/usr/local/include/vpx and -L/usr/local/lib automatically?
